# jQuery table plugin with grouping rollup

Tags: jquery

Here's an example table:

```
Location                     Sum Count Average
----------------------------------------------
- United States             9623   743      13
-   Alabama                  120    11      11
      Birmingham              20     3       7
      Montgomery              45     6       8
      ...
+   Alaska                    13     2       7
...
```

The plus and minus keys are expandos.

There are two major differences from the grouping features that most of the data grid plugins provide:

- 2 levels of rollup
- the rollup headers are more than headers, they also contain data

It would be very easy to implement this table using a few lines of Javascript.   However, I'd prefer to use one of the existing plugins to get other handy features such as sorting, pagination and column reordering for "free".

Are there any jQuery table plugins that will provide this functionality?   A quick scan of the biggies like jqGrid and dataTables makes it appear that they don't, although I haven't dug into them deep enough to say that with certainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found one:  https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable